# Transform object with nested array into a big object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I need some help to prepare my object properly to update my database

What I get from the API:

```
{
  currency: 'USD',
  product_id: '1',
  user_id: '123',
  service_id: '999',
  tech: 'javaScript',
  price: '50',
  details: [
    { detail_type: 'hours_service', value: '5' },
    { detail_type: 'workers', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'machines', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'instances', value: '1' },
    { detail_type: 'difficulty', value: '2' },
  ],
  date_start: '2021-06-20',
  date_stop: '2021-06-21',
}
```

What I need to update my DB:

```
{
  currency: 'USD',
  product_id: '1',
  user_id: '123',
  service_id: '999',
  tech: 'javaScript',
  price: '50',
  hours_service: '5',
  workers: '2',
  machines: '2',
  instances: '1',
  difficulty: '2',
  date_start: '2021-06-20',
  date_stop: '2021-06-21',
}
```

my attempt:

```
const api_data = {
  currency: 'USD',
  product_id: '1',
  user_id: '123',
  service_id: '999',
  tech: 'javaScript',
  price: '50',
  details: [
    { detail_type: 'hours_service', value: '5' },
    { detail_type: 'workers', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'machines', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'instances', value: '1' },
    { detail_type: 'difficulty', value: '2' },
  ],
  date_start: '2021-06-20',
  date_stop: '2021-06-21',
}

for (let item of api_data.details) {
  var arr = item
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    result[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

The attempt I've made gives me a lot of empty objects...

How can I make the first object `detail` array transform in key:value pair and make it one big object with all data?

thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Comment: Please show your attempt. Try to loop the `details` array or something like that. If you're stuck at a particular step, we can help. But this is not a free coding service, we're not supposed to develop your solution for you.

Comment: @JeremyThille you are absolutely right, I'm sorry it looked like I didn't even try, I'll update the question with my attempt. I never thought that was a free coding service.  I'm just looking for some help from more advanced programmers/developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce to acheive this

```js
const apiData = {
  currency: 'USD',
  product_id: '1',
  user_id: '123',
  service_id: '999',
  tech: 'javaScript',
  price: '50',
  details: [
    { detail_type: 'hours_service', value: '5' },
    { detail_type: 'workers', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'machines', value: '2' },
    { detail_type: 'instances', value: '1' },
    { detail_type: 'difficulty', value: '2' },
  ],
  date_start: '2021-06-20',
  date_stop: '2021-06-21',
};
const {details,...rest} = apiData;
const transformedObj = details.reduce((result,item)=>({...result,[item.detail_type]:item.value}),{});
const result = {...rest,...transformedObj};
console.log(result);
```